# Build List from array of objectsUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. I have a script that works, it builds an unordered list from an xml file. Then I store that list in localstorage, and on refresh, I just want to build that list from storage. I'm using the exact same script after the list is constructed in either case, but I get the

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

error at

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

when I try to load it from local storage.

I've tried many re arrangements, and I looked to see if there is a reason for it to be undefined. I can't think of one. Again, this code works when I have derived the array from XML. once I stringify and parse it back from storage, this script does not.

```
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('senatorList');
    senatorList = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
    console.log(senatorList);
    var ul = document.getElementById("members");
    for( var i = 0; i < senatorList.length; i++ )
        { 
        o = senatorList[i];

        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.name));
        li.id = o.name;
        li.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        if (o.party == 'Democrat') {
            o.voted = true;
            li.classList.add('democrat');
        } else {
            li.classList.add('republican');
        }
        ul.appendChild(li);    

}
```

Comment: ul is `null`. you are calling your code before the DOM is ready. You could run it on window.onload = function() {/* your code */};

Comment: hm. already using onload to initialize some other stuff. I'll rearrange.

Comment: you can use `window.addEventListener('load' , fn, false);` multiple times. It will run all functions in the order they are defined.

Comment: iiinteresting. just like that? or do those terms stand for something? i.e. i'm not sure what that looks like per se

Comment: You can wrap the code above in a function `function init(){}` then you can pass it as a parameter of addEventListener: `window.addEventListener('load' , init, false);`. Note init without the `()`

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null error at
>
> ul.appendChild(li);

Therefore, `ul` is null, ergo, `document.getElementById("members")` returned null - element with such an ID doesn't exist in the DOM.

I guess the code that creates `#members` and puts it in the DOM is present in the "build" part, but missing from the "rebuild from storage" part.

Answer (score 1):

Your line `var ul = document.getElementById("members");` is not returning what you expect. You can verify that by using a debugger or printing the value right after you retrieve it. `if (!ul) console.log("ul is not defined!")`. If that turns out to be the case, find out why.